# JQGrid xmlreader custom id

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-selectors, xmlreader

I need to pass a custom id to the xmlreader structure for the JQGrid to feed off of a combination of nodes in the xml data to uniquely identify the rows.
I currently have this version working

```
var feedXmlReaderOptions = {
    root: "feed",
    row: "entry",
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "d|clmNum,d|seqNum"
};
```

which concatenates the clmNum and seqNum xml nodes to build an unique identifier for the row.

By the way, the d| refers to a namespace used in the xml, so please ignore it, it's not relevant for this question.
The issue here is that I need a delimiter between the clmNum and seqNum so that I can parse the id later on, during the

```
ajaxRowOptions: {
        beforeSend:...
}
```

event, so that I can build dynamically the URL that I need to post to. The URL to post to obviously listens to the same id as the grid row, so you see the connection.
What I tried, given the CSS selector style used, were the CSS pseudo elements, through which one can insert custom, non-existent elements, into the selector:

```
d|clmNum:after { content: "_" },d|seqNum
d|clmNum.after('_'),d|seqNum
```

but it's not working...jQuery selectors complain about the {, and the jquery .after(), just like .before(), seem to work inline as methods, not arguments, after the selector returned already a result.

So, anyone has an idea about how to do this?
The alternative with returning the concatenated key during the creation of the xml doesn't work, the xml is not under my control.

Thanks a bunch.
serban@nj,usa

Added for clarifications:
My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xml:base="http://localhost:8888/eClaimWS/olddispatch.svc/">
<title type="text">DispatchManualInfo</title> 
<id>http://localhost:8888/eClaimWS/olddispatch.svc/DispatchManualInfo</id> 
<updated>2012-05-21T18:13:44Z</updated> 
<link rel="self" title="DispatchManualInfo" href="DispatchManualInfo" /> 
<entry>
<id>http://localhost:8888/eClaimWS/olddispatch.svc/DispatchManualInfo(clmNum='00C1400J0025',seqNum=1)</id> 
<title type="text" /> 
<updated>2012-05-21T18:13:44Z</updated> 
<author>
<name /> 
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="DispatchManualInfo" href="DispatchManualInfo(clmNum='00C1400J0025',seqNum=1)" /> 
<category term="eClaimDispatchProdModel.DispatchManualInfo" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /> 
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties>
<d:busPhone /> 
<d:damDesc>cat</d:damDesc> 
<d:vehColor /> 
<d:totLssInd /> 
<d:dispTransCtr m:type="Edm.Int32" m:null="true" /> 
<d:clmntCity /> 
<d:companyCd>01</d:companyCd> 
<d:insZip>07470</d:insZip> 
<d:adjZip>07701 565</d:adjZip> 
<d:vehLocSt>NJ</d:vehLocSt> 
<d:vehMake /> 
<d:lossTypeAbbr>WIND</d:lossTypeAbbr> 
<d:homePhone>201-301-5411</d:homePhone> 
<d:insLstNm>derti</d:insLstNm> 
<d:city>wayne</d:city> 
<d:adjLocalPhone>973-434-2482</d:adjLocalPhone> 
<d:vehVin>UNK99999999999999</d:vehVin> 
<d:adjName>Elaine Maniscalco</d:adjName> 
<d:lstChgUser>Vendor</d:lstChgUser> 
<d:seqNum m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:seqNum> 
<d:clmNum>00C1400J0025</d:clmNum> 
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
......
</feed>
```

I cannot use feed>entry>id for configuring the xmlreader id parameter, because the id node is too big and causes all sorts of problems as a rowid for the grid...
What I need is a short version of the id node, something like 00C1400J0025_1. 
Since clmNum and seqNum are also present independently in the XML, I wanted to use the xmlreader with

```
id: "d|clmNum:after { content: "_" },d|seqNum"
```

and that didn't work.
With

```
id: "d|clmNum,d|seqNum"
```

the rowid becomes 00C1400J00251 and I have a hard time parsing it, because the clmNum can be anything, of any length.

Comment: I am afraid that your have to include an example of the XML data which you use as input and the jqGrid definition (JavaScript code) which you use. ithout the information it's very difficult to understand your problems.

Comment: The XML looks like this:

Comment: You should click "edit" link under your question and append the text with new information. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) is described how to format the code.

Comment: Sorry, the comment didn't allow enough characters...edited initial message above with extra info...thank you Oleg for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `beforeProcessing` callback to normalize the `<id>` values of the `<entry>` elements from

```
<id>http://localhost:8888/eClaimWS/olddispatch.svc/DispatchManualInfo(clmNum='00C1400J0025',seqNum=1)</id>
```

to

```
<id>00C1400J0025_1</id>
```

To implement this you can use `RegEx` for example.

After that you can easy fill the grid with the information which you need. To read information from elements having namespace or some other special characters you can escape the character with two backslashes: `\\` (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) information about escaping meta-characters). For example to read element `d:adjName` you can use `xmlmap: 'd\\:adjName'`. The approach work perfect in all browsers with exception webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari). As the workaround one can use `xmlmap: 'd\\:adjName, adjName'` because `xmlmap: 'adjName'` will work in Chrome and Safari. I personally find better the way with the usage of `getElementsByTagNameNS`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomXmlReader.htm) looks like:

[image]

and have the following code

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "CustomXmlReader.xml",
    colModel: [
        {name: 'id'}, // optional
        {name: 'updated', formatter: 'date'},
        {name: 'adjName', xmlmap: function (entry) { // 'd\\:adjName, adjName'
                var nodes;
                if (entry.getElementsByTagNameNS) {
                    nodes = entry.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices", "adjName");
                } else {
                    // old IE browsers
                    nodes = entry.getElementsByTagName("d:adjName");
                }
                return nodes.length > 0 ? nodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue : "";
            }}
    ],
    gridview: true,
    height: "auto",
    xmlReader: {
        root: "feed",
        row: "entry",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "id"
    },
    beforeProcessing: function (data) {
        $(data).children("feed").children("entry").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).find(">id"),
                res = /\(clmNum='([0-9A-Z]+)',seqNum=(\d+)\)$/g.exec(id.text());
            id.text(res[1] + "_" + res[2]);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: As always, Oleg, awesome to have you among us! Your answer is more than I wanted because it actually teaches us on how to massage the data coming from data sources that are not under our control. Many, many thanks.